# not able to resolve string to GeoCoordinate HERE maps. My method resolveAddress is not working

Tags: android, geocoding, here-api

//my variables

private static GeoCoordinate fromLocation;
private static GeoCoordinate toLocation ;

```
private List<Location> locationList;
private EditText m_fromLocation;
private EditText m_toLocation;
```

//In onCreate I am defining these:

```
    m_fromLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fromText);
    m_toLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.toText);
```

When I enter fromLocation and toLocation then I press Go! button from the UI and the getDirections method is called. In this I am trying to resolve address which user enters in the form of text string to GeoCoordinates.

// Functionality for taps of the "Go!" button
    public void getDirections(View view) {

```
    fromLocation = resolveAddress(m_fromLocation.getText().toString());
    toLocation= resolveAddress(m_toLocation.getText().toString());

    // 1. clear previous results
    //textViewResult.setText("");
    if (map != null && mapRoute != null) {
        map.removeMapObject(mapRoute);
        mapRoute = null;
    }

    // 2. Initialize RouteManager
    RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager();

    // 3. Select routing options
    RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();

    RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
    routeOptions.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR);
    routeOptions.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);
    routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);

    // 4. Select Waypoints for your routes

    // START
    routePlan.addWaypoint(fromLocation);

    // END
    routePlan.addWaypoint(toLocation);

    // 5. Retrieve Routing information via RouteManagerEventListener

    RouteManager.Error error = routeManager.calculateRoute(routePlan, routeManagerListener);
    if (error != RouteManager.Error.NONE) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Route calculation failed with: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}
```

This is the method which returns GeoCoordinate of the string query. But this is not working. 
public GeoCoordinate resolveAddress(String query)
    {

```
    GeoCoordinate coordinate = null;

    if(!query.isEmpty()) {
        //query text fields for geo coordinates

        ResultListener<List<Location>> listener = new GeocodeListener();
        GeocodeRequest request = new GeocodeRequest(query);
        if (request.execute(listener) != ErrorCode.NONE) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Geocode request resulted with an error");

        } else {
            if (!locationList.isEmpty()) {
                coordinate = locationList.get(0).getCoordinate();
            }
        }

        return coordinate;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"address is empty, cannot be resolved");

        return coordinate;
    }
}

class GeocodeListener implements ResultListener<List<Location>> {
    // Implementation of ResultListener

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<Location> data, ErrorCode error) {
        if (error != ErrorCode.NONE) {
            return;

        } else {

            if (!data.isEmpty()) {

                locationList = data;

            } else {
                locationList = null;
                Log.d("GeocodeListener", "location list is empty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is the gson jar added to the libs folder for app as mentioned in documentation (https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple.html)
2. set the search center when doing the geocode request , an example would be as follows :
   GeocodeRequest request = new GeocodeRequest(query).setSearchArea(mMap.getCenter(),5000);
3. Kindly Parse the results only in  onCompleted () method of GeocodeListner and not in resolveAddress()